# Multiplying paired elements in python using reduce

Tags: python, list, reduce, python-itertools

For a list like:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to use the code below to multiply paired elements like this:

```
(a[0] + a[1]) * (a[2] + a[3]) * (a[4] + a[5])
```

I've tried using something like:

```
reduce((lambda x, y: (x+y)), numbers)
```

and:

```
reduce((lambda x, y: (x+y)*(x+y)), numbers)
```

But I don't know how to make it work over the entire list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The entire solution must fit withing the reduce and I cannot import any other modules.

Comment: You need to iterate in pairs, add the numbers *then* reduce a multiplication over the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in two steps:

1. sum consecutive items in the list: `[sum(a[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(a), 2)]`
2. apply the reduction:  `reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, new_list)`

---

Compose them together:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [sum(a[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(a), 2)])
```

Comment: I came here to say this, except that instead of a lambda I used `int.__mul__`, assuming that the items in the list are always integers.

Comment: Probably better to use `sum(a[i:i+2])` otherwise this won't work for odd-length lists (currently throws an IndexError). Otherwise great solution!

Answer (score 4):

You could `reduce` your own generator that gives the sum of the pairs in your iterable:

```
def pairwise_sum(seq):
    odd_length = len(seq) % 2

    it = iter(seq)
    for item1, item2 in zip(it, it):
        yield item1 + item2
    if odd_length:
        yield seq[-1]

>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, pairwise_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
231
```

Or if you want it more general, you could use the [`grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to add all pairs and then use `reduce` to multiply all sums:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

>>> reduce(mul, map(sum, grouper([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2, fillvalue=0)))
231
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the only import I can use is reduce.

Comment: You could've said that in the question.

Comment: @T.J. No problem, I updated the answer including a version that doesn't rely on imports.

Comment: Super clever solution!